# I accidently deleted my taskbar - how do I get it back?

Tags: raspbian, taskbar

> Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

I recently was messing around with my Pi when I accidentally deleted the taskbar. I cannot figure out how to bring it back.

I was on the desktop when I highlighted two icons on the left side of the taskbar, one called "Panel 1" and the other called "Panel 2". I figured I didn't want two panels, so I right clicked Panel 2 and deleted it. That ended up deleting my taskbar!

How can I bring it back? I'm using the latest version of Raspbian.

Comment: Linux, including Debian (and raspbian, which is derived from it) has a heterogeneous range of desktop GUIs, meaning there is not just one "Desktop Environment" (aka. DE) to rule them all.  Different DE's deal with things like taskbars differently, so you need to be specific -- but presumably you are using *LXDE*, since that is the raspbian default.  The raspberry pi community represents a very tiny minority of linux/debian/LXDE users, hence you are better off asking general questions about such elsewhere -- which is why I recommended this be closed.

Comment: That said, I'm not an LXDE user personally (there are many other options, debian/raspbian wise), but I would bet if you click on the root window, or bump the cursor along an edge, you'll find a menu that leads you somewhere...if not, look for **LXDE** documentation online.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Desktop Managers, and not about the Pi.

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 18):

I did exactly the same thing. You can fix it by copying a default panel back:

(adapted from https://askubuntu.com/questions/64631/how-to-restore-the-default-lubuntu-panel)

```
cd ~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE/panels
cp /usr/share/lxpanel/profile/default/panels/panel .
sudo reboot
```

Cheers!

With Raspbian Jessie (2016-11-25), it would be

```
cd ~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels
curl -O https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ColinNg/9ed317308a9a0f75824f828e75c8469c/raw/a72176416201a0e6ebbce30608e6f7eceb379e0e/panel
sudo reboot
```

And with Raspbian Buster (2019-07-10):

```
cp /etc/xdg/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel /home/pi/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

Restart your Pi. The deletion is only temporary  and will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new user and logging in as that user, then start lxde and see if that user has a panel.  If that works, maybe you can copy the lxde config file from that user to your `pi` user.

Answer (score 0):

I also Deleted accidentally but recovered this way
There was one more task-bar on top of Screen 
right click on top taskbar>>Panel Setting>>Gemetry tab>>Make postion Bottom

right click on top taskbar>>Add/Remove panel Item
select Panel Applets Tab >> Add >> Select Task Bar(Window list) >> Click Add 
Now you can all apps open.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the corrrect fix yet, but if I type "lxpanel &" in a terminal emulator I get a working taskbar again.  (logout doesn't work)  You can also put a line "lxpanel &" in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc to make it more permanent.

From this you should have figured out that lxpanel is just a program that runs, what you have to do to start it is more an annoyance than anything.

I had been logged in via VNC (and installed tightvncserver remotely via ssh) and when I came back to the physical machine the taskbar was gone, so I started Googling.  VNC maintains a set of preferences files which mostly parallel X(org) in ~/$HOME/.vnc/xstartup and it's possible something went in there by accident.  The more normal config files are in ~/$HOME/.config/lxpanel and lxsession, then some system-wide ones in /etc/xdg/lxpanel and lxsession.  But it's quite a maze, the lazy fix would be to experiment with replacing those files with ones from another machine.  Just remember you can run lxpanel from multiple places if you get stuck.  I can get to obconf just fine but I don't see anything in there that looks like a fix.  You want a default set of config files.  And you'll need to get out of X and back in, or reboot, to be sure you've cured it.

And BTW this is in 64 bit Debian Stretch on a Rock64, looks about the same as the Raspberry Pi I'm typing this on.  And the same as LXDE in Wheezy on an amd64 machine, it's not at all peculiar to a Raspberry Pi.

When you're poking around in there (I used mc) look for files with recent dates.  But maybe they got deleted too.  I see changes in ~/$HOME/.config/lxpanel/LXDE/panels/panel and ~/$HOME/.config/lxpanel/default/panels/panel.  I've replaced those 2 files with an original panel file from another arm64 machine.  Now when it's booting I see the taskbar flash twice but then it goes away.  Still a work in progress.  Keep notes, one of the principle Lnux trade secrets.