# taskbar got hidden after raspberrypi update

Tags: raspi-config, taskbar

I have recently updated my raspberry pi wheezy.After rebooting I could figure out that the taskbar has gone.I have referred many solutions as some have deleted the taskbar [I accidently deleted my taskbar - how do I get it back?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9395/i-accidently-deleted-my-taskbar-how-do-i-get-it-back)

But the above doesn't work for me.Is there any solution for overcoming it.

Comment: @Milliways actually I need to install iceweasel.When I try to install that I found that I need to update it first.So I have updated it.Now should I again install the raspbian OS.

Comment: I misread your question. I thought you had attempted to update to Jessie.

Comment: @Milliways can I recover it.Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is identified and probable fix is provided in the last post of this link.
[After 5/13 Raspbian update, desktop menu is missing](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=148030&p=974857)

I was able to fix my issue using above link. Hope it helps you too...!

Comment: Could you please summarise the information in the link in your answer, it saves people having to keep chasing links.

Answer (score 0):

**I know it's nearly two years later, so this is for other people that find this, like me.**

I had this same problem, and as I'm a complete noob on Linux, a lot of googling was done, and I found another article here on stackexchange with someone that has a slightly different problem. The top answer fixed my panel issue, so it's worth a shot if you have the same problem. Hope it helps!

[I accidently deleted my taskbar - how do I get it back?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9395/i-accidently-deleted-my-taskbar-how-do-i-get-it-back)

Comment: Link-based answers are discouraged as links can become dead over time. Please modify your answer to contain the gist of what specifically needs to be done.